# Why might trees work so much better than boosting classifiers?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I am predicting 10 classes label encoded using scikit-learn with 6 factors, 1.2M cases.
DecisionTreeClassifier
RandomForestClassifier
ExtraTreesClassifier
give accuracies (and precision and recall) of 0.9

AdaBoostClassifier
GradientBoostingClassifier
give accuracies of 0.2

Any pointers on the huge discrepancy?

(I am doing gridsearchcv).
Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

def output_metrics():
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
    print("Accuracy:",accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print('Precision', precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None).mean())
    print('Recall', recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None).mean())


from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

tree_para =  { 'n_estimators': [16, 32] }
clf = GridSearchCV(AdaBoostClassifier(), tree_para, cv=5)
model= clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test) 

output_metrics()
```

Comment: It could be that boosting classifiers are overfitting.

Comment: How do scores compare for train vs. validation/test data?

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you double-check these accuracies (e.g., calculate them yourself by hand). If I had to guess, I'd guess accuracy is being calculated differently for the different models. Perhaps 0.9 is one-vs-rest (2-way) accuracy and 0.2 is 10-way accuracy? What happens if you run https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html yourself for each best model?

Comment: @Akavall if they are overfitting wouldn't their metrics be better rather than worse than the trees?

Comment: @Sammy not sure how to do it for test as it its already used? Could  you point me in right direction please?  I have added code.

Comment: I would like to see how well your AdaBoost learns the training data. You can get the accuracy of the best estimator in your ```GridSearchCV```using ```clf.best_score_```. And ```clf.best_params_``` would be interesting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I would like to point out that the performance in this specific case might still be due to the specific dataset used.

A likely explanation lies in the essence of what trees and boosting algorithms do.

As @akvall pointed out in the comments, Boosting algorithms can often overfit since this is what they are designed to do! As a reminder, regardless of how fancy a boosting algorithm works, it follows the following logic:

- train on the training set
- evaluate to see which mistakes were made
- retrain and focus more on the previous mistakes
- repeat until satisfactory results

Trees do not work the same way and are therefore less prone to overfitting. A Random Forest will simply compute independent trees and use majority voting to make a prediction.

Every boosting algorithm will "boost" for a certain amount of iterations, it is probably wise to look at how many times your algorithms did "boost".

Comment: If they are overfitting wouldn't their metrics be better rather than worse than the trees?

Comment: Neatly explained!

Comment: @schoon if they overfit, their metrics will likely be better on the training set but worse on the test set, which seems to be what's happening now since GridSearchCV is used